A reference for the chromatic number of graphs when introducing twins
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph. Let $\omega(G)$ be the clique number of $G$ and $\chi(G)$ the chromatic number of $G$. The neighbourhood of a vertex, $v\in V$, is the set of vertices adjacent to $v$ and is denoted by $N(v)$. The closed neighbourhood of a vertex, $v\in V$, is $N(v)\cup v$ and is denoted by $N[v]$.
Two vertices, $v,w\in V$, are true twins if they are non-adjacent in $G$ and share the same neighbourhood, $N(v)=N(w)$. Note that if $v_1,\ldots, v_m$, are true twins then they form an independent set. Two vertices, $v,w\in V$, are false twins if they are adjacent in $G$ and $N[v]=N[w]$. Note that if $v_1,\ldots, v_m$, are false twins then they form a clique set.
Let $v$ be in $G$. Let $H$ be a graph formed by adding a vertex $s$ to $G$ where $s$ is a true twin of $v$, i.e. $N(v)=N(s)$. Then it is clear that in any proper colouring of $H$, we can colour $s$ and $v$ by the same colour and so $\chi(G)=\chi(H)$.
Now let $T=(V',E')$ be a graph formed by adding $m$ vertices, $r_1,\ldots, r_m$, to $G$ such that each $r_i$ is a false twin to some $v\in V$, i.e. $N[v]=N[r_i]$. As sets of pairwise false twins form a clique, every set of pairwise false twins in $T$ has size at most $\omega(T)$. Then $\chi(T)\leq \chi(G)\omega(T)$.
I wish to use these results in a paper but it seems like there is probably an existing paper I can cite for proofs of these results rather than needing to include the proofs in the paper. Please could you let me know of anywhere I can find these results or results that imply them.
